# Config homestead to map more than 1 project

Tags: laravel, homestead

I have mapped one project in the homestead yaml file and runs perfectly
but I tried to figure out how it works if I map more than one site

The domain name that is specified in the file as a second site I want to map is in this case called lkprojects.app

To be more concrete I want to direct to my lkprojects.app homestead domain
but it fails and I have tried with the serve command and homestead provision

So I'm a little confused about how I get that to work using the lkprojects.app domain

My homestead.yaml file looks like:

```
<code>

---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\leo\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/leo/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/

sites:
    - map: athliit.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/athliit/public
    - map: lkprojects.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/lkprojects/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - athliit
    - lkprojects

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

</code>
```

So if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong I would like some input.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. Make sure you have added them to your hosts file:
   `192.168.10.10 athliit.app
   192.168.10.10 lkprojects.app`
   In windows it's located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. OSX/Linux in `/etc/hosts`
2. Have you ran `vagrant provision`? This will propagate any config changes to your homestead instance

Comment: i have added them to my hosts file so no problem there 

and i have runned vagrant provision 
and tried to even restart my virtual machine and tried again 
but if i try even it actually goes to my localhost 127.0.0.1 and i have set athliit and lkprojects.app to 192.168.10.10